# How to replace one iframe with another

Tags: iframe, flash

So I have this html wrapper from Flash CS5.5, but the swf file isn't showing the video skin in PHP unless I use iframe. The problem I am having is I would like to use a similar outcome to this

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="980" height="380" id="g-max_banner" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="im/stuff/vid.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
            <param name="play" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="wmode" value="window" />
            <param name="scale" value="showall" />
            <param name="menu" value="true" />
            <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
            <param name="salign" value="" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="im/stuff/vid.swf" width="980" height="380">
                <param name="movie" value="im/stuff/vid.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <iframe width="980" height="380" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLlLcNiMNCMn_4dR6TZQCTVfY7qo51VJ8A"></iframe>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
```

So that when someone doesn't have flash it pulls the youtube playlist instead. Is there a way I can do this using iframe since the video skin embedded in the swf doesn't show up on the webpage using the above code? I have tested it with a basic iframe call and the skin shows up, so I know it works fine. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I fixed it. You can use the html wrapper in php that Flash creates. You just need to put the skin file in the root folder on your website host where the configuration file is.